# How to get caller name for a method in Java

Tags: java, spring, interceptor

I have an API that has many operations like getX, getY, getZ etc. and many write operations like writeX, writeY and writeZ etc.
Since this is a rest service and each controller method is mapped with specific operation name.

```
@Controller(url) //just an example 
getX(param1, param2){

}
```

I have data access layer that interacts with dynamodb tables. I am planning to add the read and write capacity metrics to my DAO layer so that I would know which API is costly.
An API can access multiple dynamodb table at once.
Given this, if I want to know which API made call to the dynamodb, I will have to pass in the operation name from controller--> manager --> DAO methods.
that will require a lot of code refactoring.

Is there a better and efficient way to get the topmost caller name inside the DAO layer without passing the method names.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to manipulate but this can do the trick

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

Basically the higher the index, the less recent the method call is. Although it might seem tempting, the controller will not be the first method to be called, not always. What you can do tho is use the method `.getClassName()` and maybe get the last item of the array containing the "Controller" word withing the class name.